# Integrating weekly e-mail delivery/newsletter with Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, email

For my Spring-based web application, I now have the requirement to send out weekly e-mails to my application's users.

What are elegant solutions to this requirements?

Up until now, I have come up with the following possible solutions:

- a **dedicated** cron job that I schedule to run once a week, running independently from my web application JVM process and outside of the web application Servlet container. 
   This process takes care of sending out those weekly e-mails. To accomplish sending *personalized* e-mails, it reuses domain classes (such as my `User` class) that I have already developed for my web application. This dedicated process accesses my application's MySQL database concurrently to the running Spring Web MVC servlet?
- a scheduled mechanism **inside** my *Spring Web MVC* servlet or **inside** my *Servlet container*. 
  In this setup, the e-mail sending happens inside the same JVM and the same servlet container as my web-serving Spring Web MVC servlet. Maybe this setup has (irrelevant?) advantages such as "database connection pool sharing" and "transaction sharing" "class sharing" with the servlet hosted inside the same environment.
- Using or not using **Spring Batch**, for any of the above conceived setups.
   I have no experience right now with Spring Batch as to judge whether Spring Batch is or isn't an adequate tool for my requirement.

Maybe there are other solutions as well?

I am especially interested in answers that can give insights and guide in making an educated decision.

<sub>It is irrelevant for this particular question whether e-mails get sent with my own infrastructure or with a third party e-mail SaaS service.</sub>

Comment: Depends on what should happen when the server was down while regular mail sending time: a) immediately sending after when the server comes up again, b) or skip this mails and wait for the next week sending slot. c) don´t care about, the server is always running. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From your description, the code for generating newsleters must share common code base with your main application. So the natural solution is to develop this code withing your main application. The open case is how this code is triggered:

1. From CRON. You start a script from CRON that would trigger the function within you application *somehow*. This somehow may be a process listening on specific port, or, what is quite natural for web application, a dedicated URL that would trigger newsletter. Just make sure that URL can't be run from outside, only from localhost (check caller IP, for example). You must, however, deal with the situation, that your app is down (restarting for example) when CRON launches the script.
2. From within the application. For example, using Quartz. The minus is that you need to include new library, create database tables for Quartz. The plus - Quartz will handle situation, when the task was scheduled on the moment when the application was down, because it stores the information about what was launched in DB.

Answer (score 1):

We always use cron to fire a JMS message to a queue and have a dedicated process which consumes these messages. You can add the email contents to the message or just use the message as a trigger. The nice thing about this approach is you can fire in a JMS message from anywhere and have multiple handlers lots of different email scenarios. The only downside is installing a JMS broker, if you don't already have one...

Answer (score 1):

I am building a Spring-MVC based web application which is required to send a weekly newsletter to a small group of people. I am using Spring's built-in scheduling mechanism. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html‎

Yes, in this setup, the e-mail sending happens inside the same JVM and the same servlet container and it is quite easy and handy to implement the solution. I am observing the stability and reliability of this mechanism and cannot feedback more about it now.